# StackOverflowException in JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode

Tags: json, json.net, overflow

We recently upgraded to Json.NET 10.0r2 from 6.0.1 and since upgrading I noticed that one of our unit tests throws a Stack Overflow Exception when trying to deserialize invalid Json.  The purpose of the test was to ensure handling of invalid Json.  This same test used to throw a JsonSerializationException, but now is bringing down nUnit with the StackOverflow.

I've replicated it in Json.NET's own unit testing project with this test:

```
[Test]
public void FailOnInvalidJSON( )
{
    string json = @"{'Row' : ";

    Assert.Throws<JsonSerializationException>(()=>JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "ROOT"));
}
```

Any ideas on work a work-around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

And promptly [fixed](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1290) in change set [`822c3f0`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/822c3f00dd8e49c6dbe762012272a70ab78dc70d).  Should be in the next release after 10.0.2.

**Original Answer**

It looks like a change to [`JsonTextReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonTextReader.htm) in version 8.0.1 may have uncovered a bug in [`XmlNodeConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_XmlNodeConverter.htm).

In [7.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/7.0.1), when the unexpected end of file is reached, [`JsonReader.TokenType`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_TokenType.htm) becomes `JsonToken.None` after the next attempt to [`Read()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_Read.htm), which causes [`DeserializeNode()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L2158) to throw an `Unexpected JsonToken when deserializing node: None` exception.  But in [8.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/8.0.1) and later the `TokenType` appears to stay stuck at the type of the last encountered token, namely `JsonToken.PropertyName`, which causes the infinite recursion.

The correct fix would be, in [`XmlNodeConverter.DeserializeNode()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L2171) around line 2171, to check the return from `reader.Read()`:

```
case JsonToken.PropertyName:
    if (currentNode.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Document && document.DocumentElement != null)
    {
        throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "JSON root object has multiple properties. The root object must have a single property in order to create a valid XML document. Consider specifying a DeserializeRootElementName.");
    }

    string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
    // Need to check the return from reader.Read() here:
    if (!reader.Read())
    {
        throw JsonSerializationException.Create(reader, "Unexpected end of file when deserializing property: " + propertyName );
    }
```

... And it appears there are a few more places in [`XmlNodeConverter.cs`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L2171) where the return from `reader.Read()` needs to be checked, for instance in `ReadAttributeElements(JsonReader reader, XmlNamespaceManager manager)` around [line 1942](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Converters/XmlNodeConverter.cs#L1942).

You could [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) if you want.

In the meantime, your options for a workaround would be:

- Corrupt the JSON in a different manner, for instance like so:

  ```
  string json = @"{'Row' : }";
  ```

  And check for the more general exception `JsonException`.
- Pre-parse the JSON into a `JToken`:

  ```
  Assert.Throws<JsonException>(()=>JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JToken.Parse(json).ToString(), "ROOT"));
  ```